# Not able to access JSON API and giving me reference error

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am getting a reference error when trying to access the following API [formula one API](http://ergast.com/api/f1/2007/driverStandings.json)

The error I am getting is that I am not able access MRData.  I have used JSON Editor and I am sure I have the correct pathway.  Below is the post request.

```
app.get('/about', function(req, res){
res.render('about', {standings: null});
});

app.post('/about', function(req, res){
var year = req.body.Year;

var url = `http://ergast.com/api/f1/${year}/driverstandings.json?callback=`
request(url, function (err, response, body){
  if(err){
    res.render('about', {standings: null, error: 'Error, please try again'});
  } else {
    let standings = JSON.parse(body)
    if(standings.MRData === undefined) {
      res.render('about', {standings: null, error: 'Error, please try again'});
    } else {
      let firstName = MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists[0].DriverStandings[0].Driver.givenName
      let standingsText = `The winner of the formula 1 championship in the year ${MRData.StandingsTable.season} is ${firstName}`;
      res.render('about', {standings: standingsText, error: null});
    }
   }

 });

 });
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you for looking into this.

Comment: i don't think you can do jsonp callbacks in node.js like that bud. i mean you probably could by `eval()`'ing the response, but i'd consider it dangerous. better to use a library someone already built and tested for this purpose. you may want to look into using the following library https://github.com/then/then-jsonp

Comment: What exactly is the error message? What line does it occur on in the above snippet?

Comment: this is the error message i am getting ```/Users/briankaty1/Desktop/Udemy_WebCourse/weather_api/index.js:77
          let firstName = MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists[0].DriverStandings[0].Driver.givenName```

Comment: The below answer points to the same error. It will fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is 1 syntax error and 1 optional scenario I can think of.

**Syntax error:**

In the `else` part you are directly referencing `MRData` whereas you should reference it by `standings.MRData`. Both for `firstName` and `standingsText`

```
let firstName = standings.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists[0].DriverStandings[0].Driver.givenName
let standingsText = `The winner of the formula 1 championship in the year ${standings.MRData.StandingsTable.season} is ${firstName}`;
```

**Another Scenario** is `req.body.Year` maybe blank and you are using that so console logging the url may lead to a solution.

Comment: downvoter: I don't see what is the problem, I clearly see there are syntax errors and I pointed them out. Even if the problem lies  elsewhere this fix had to be done, otherwise any answer would've resulted in 'no, not working, still reference error'